# Add a field to a custom Payment method (frontend)

Tags: payment, checkout, forms, layout

I would like to add a field in the checkout page for a custom payment method.

Actually because my method extends CC the form is automatically generated (I have no layout set) look at -> `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods` with `getPaymentMethodFormHtml()` function:

```
    public function getPaymentMethodFormHtml(Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract $method)
{
     return $this->getChildHtml('payment.method.' . $method->getCode());
}
```

This is good however I would like to add a comment form ( only for this payment method ) using a custom layout:
keep the current form and add an extra block with an text input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your payment model, you should set `protected $_formBlockType = 'foo/form';` class that derives from `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` and create a template/foo/form.phtml file.
This allows you to write your own form file.

Then you need to override `assignData($data)` function (payment model) in order to save this extra field value in the `$paymentInfo` obj.

In case you will need to show that field in info as well you can do the same as above with $_infoBlockType variable.

Comment: right :) I just did it

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link

for doing it using a module created for it

[this is the link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page)

Comment: Welcome to magento.se and Thanks for the answer! To be sure, that this information is still available in a few months or years, please copy (rewrite) the most important informations from the blogpost here.

Comment: the link will stay, hopefully some more years to come.
that's a lengthy process, which is why I provided the link.